# How to convert Coda 2 clips to Sublime Text snippets?

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets, coda

I want to switch from Coda 2 to Sublime Text 2. The only reason I'm stuck in Coda 2 is my long collection of clips of my own.

Any idea on how to convert the clips from Coda to snippets for Sublime Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an OSX tool called [clips2snippets](https://github.com/oame/clips2snippets) that will help converting your Coda 2 clips into Sublime Text snippets.

Once you have it installed, just run:

```
clips2snippets gen HTML.clips
```

Replace `HTML.clips` with your current clips.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory

Answer (score 0):

Run this in terminal and clip2snippets will be installed without any error:

sudo gem install clips2snippets